# JSON Data Read in Hive Table

Tags: json, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am able to create Hive table using JSON Serde `org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe` but when I am reading the data from Hive table I am unable to read.

```
hive> create table emp (EmpId int , EmpFirstName string , EmpLastName string) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe';
OK
Time taken: 2.148 seconds

hive> LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/cloudera/EmpData/emp.json' INTO table emp;
Loading data to table employee.emp
chgrp: changing ownership of 'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/employee.db/emp/emp.json': User does not belong to supergroup
Table employee.emp stats: [numFiles=1, totalSize=4163]
OK
Time taken: 1.141 seconds

hive> select * from emp;
OK
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: A JSONObject text must end with '}' at 2 [character 3 line 1]
Time taken: 0.504 seconds
```

Answer (score 1):

ERROR: Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: **Row is not a valid JSON Object** - JSONException: A JSONObject text must end with '}' at 2 [character 3 line 1]

check the json provided in /user/cloudera/EmpData/emp.json is valid

You can eliminate the invalid row by

```
ALTER TABLE table emp SET SERDEPROPERTIES ( "ignore.malformed.json" = "true");
```

check this link -> https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde

Edit:
this is invalid json

`{ "cols": [ "EmpId", "EmpFirstName", "EmpLastName" ], "data": [ [ 1, "Hannah", "Walton" ], [ 2, "Barrett", "Mendoza" ], [ 3, "Camden", "Kidd" ], [ 4, "Illiana", "Collier" ] ] }`

the json provided by you has

`key:cols and value:[ "EmpId", "EmpFirstName", "EmpLastName" ]`

and

`key :data and value :[ [ 1, "Hannah", "Walton" ], [ 2, "Barrett", "Mendoza" ], [ 3, "Camden", "Kidd" ], [ 4, "Illiana", "Collier" ]`

the json should be something like

```
{"EmpId":1,"EmpFirstName":"Hannah","EmpLastName":"Walton"}
{"EmpId":2,"EmpFirstName":"Barrett","EmpLastName":"Mendoza"}
{"EmpId":3,"EmpFirstName":"Camden","EmpLastName":"Kidd"}
```

Comment: First I would like to thank you for your response.
I tried the option that you suggested but now i am getting "null" for  all fields. My JSON file is correct and i am able to parse it correctly.
Please see my sample data which is causing issue in Hive table:
{
 "cols": [
  "EmpId",
  "EmpFirstName",
  "EmpLastName"
 ],
 "data": [
  [
   1,
   "Hannah",
   "Walton"
  ],
  [
   2,
   "Barrett",
   "Mendoza"
  ],
  [
   3,
   "Camden",
   "Kidd"
  ],
  [
   4,
   "Illiana",
   "Collier"
  ]
 ]
}